# "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation." when building a Visual Studio 2010 VSPackage

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vspackage

I recently create a couple of VSPackages for some Visual Studio extensions (menu bar/command).  I compiled them correctly yesterday, checked into TFS (i'm the only one touching this project, FYI).  I had already installed these extensions and were working fine.  Today it doesn't compile!  I get the following error:

**Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.**

This doesn't tell me anything, so i fired up Visual Studio with the following command:

devenv.exe  /Rebuild > out.log

In my out.log, I see the following:

**C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\VSSDK\Microsoft.VsSDK.targets(420,5): error : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.**

I have been stuck on this for hours and can no longer build these VSPackages.  Anyone?  This is really frustrating.  I have already tried cleaning project/rebuilding/build using Visual Studio itself (not command line)

Answer (score 6):

I've experienced this issue several times in both vs2010 and vs2012, and manually deleting the "bin" and "obj" folders from the project then doing a "rebuild" normally does the trick.

Comment: I had this issue with VS 2013 in a Xamarin.iOS project. Additionally, to the above solution I had to close and re-open VS for it to work properly...

Comment: deleting the "bin" and "obj" DID Solve the problem!! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Further to the answer provided by the OP, I will provide it here for completeness instead of relying on the external link remaining live:

Quoted directly from the MSDN forum answer:

> Do you happen to have these extensions installed to the AllUsers
>   location (i.e. %VSInstallDir%\Common7\IDE\Extensions)?
>
> You mentioned in your initial post that "I had already installed these
>   extensions and were working fine."
>
> The task that's failing (based on the line number in the targets file)
>   is the UninstallExtension task. The only reason I'm thinking this task
>   would execute and fail in your situation is if you're building an
>   extension that's already installed to the Common7\IDE\Extensions
>   directory.
>
> Regards, Aaron

I find myself on this question because of exactly the same build issue of a VSIX Installer Project for our project templates. This solved my issue.

Indeed, I uninstalled the prior version of our templates and the build occurs without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you double checked that all of your projects are using compatible framework versions?
As in you can't use a .Net 4.0 assembly in a .Net 3.5 project.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Yes I have doubled checked this.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Is the project linked with source control like TFS? If so then take latest from TFS and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Visual Studio as **Administrator**?

Maybe you have insufficient rights for some file (copy/move/delete) especially in bin or obj folders.