# error occured in TFS-exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: visual-studio-2013

TFS Error

```
Error Description: exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation
```

When I am opening TFS in Visual Studio 2013
I cannot checkin the files also due to this.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have **run VS with Administrator**. And if you have some extensions installed, you can disable them first then do the check in action again.

More ways please refer the similarly question ["Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation." when building a Visual Studio 2010 VSPackage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823691/exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation-when-building-a-visu)

If above is still not work, you can also try to [delete tfs and vs cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/) *(Note: back up your pending changes first)*.